# How to integrate $\int_n^{+\infty} x \exp\{-ax^2+bx+c\}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

How can I integrate,

$$
\int_n^{+\infty} x \exp\{-ax^2+bx+c\}dx
$$

and what's the result w.r.t the Gaussian function's p.d.f $p(x)$ and c.d.f $\phi(x)$?

Thanks!

Comment: @DilipSarwate c.d.f of course. Thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing the square in the quadratic:
$$\eqalign{
\int_n^\infty x \exp(-ax^2+bx+c)\,dx
&= \int_n^\infty\kern-5pt x \exp( -a(x-{\textstyle{b\over 2a})^2 +c+{b^2\over 4a} }  )\,dx\cr
&= \alpha \int_n^\infty\kern-5pt  x \exp( \textstyle {-(x-{\textstyle{b\over 2a})^2   }\over 1/a } )\,dx\cr
&=  \alpha \int_n^\infty\kern-5pt   (x+{\textstyle{b\over 2a}-{b\over2a}}) \exp( \textstyle {-(x-{\textstyle{b\over 2a})^2   }\over 1/a } )\,dx\cr
&=\alpha \int_n^\infty\kern-5pt   (x { -{\textstyle{b\over2a}}}) \exp( {\textstyle {-(x-{\textstyle{b\over 2a})^2   }\over 1/a }} )\,dx 
+ \alpha\int_n^\infty\kern-5pt   \textstyle{b\over2a}  \exp( \textstyle {-(x-{\textstyle{b\over 2a})^2   }\over 1/a } )\,dx,\cr
}
$$
where $\alpha=\exp(c+{b^2\over4a})$.

On the right hand side of the last equality above, the first integral can be evaluated using the substitution $u=x-{b\over 2a}$ and the second integral can be expressed in terms of the cumulative distribution function of an appropriate normal random variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since 
$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\exp(-ax^2+bx+c) = (-2ax+b)\exp(-ax^2+bx+c)$, you can
massage the given integrand to something of the form 
$$\frac{-1}{2a}\int (-2ax+b)\exp(-ax^2+bx+c)\ \mathrm dx
+ \int \frac{b}{2a}\exp(-ax^2+bx+c)\ \mathrm dx$$
where the first integral now has a perfect integrand and the second,
after further massaging will give
you something involving $\Phi(\cdot)$, the cdf of the standard normal 
(Gaussian) random variable. Note that @Wonder's answer does not get
the second term.